# Kafka Streams Store Table of latest combination of values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to store the latest combination of occurrences of values in a table.
So messages are coming in for Patients and Sensors:

```
{ patient: "A", sensor: "X1", measurementTime: 1625501773},
{ patient: "A", sensor: "Y1", measurementTime: 1625501773},
{ patient: "B", sensor: "X2", measurementTime: 1625501772}
```

I would like to keep a list updated per patient, the latest measurement time per sensor. Does anybody know how to do this using the Kafka Streams API?

I was thinking of something like the following:

```
KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier PatientSensorSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("latest-patient-sensor-occurrence");

KStream<String, SensorData> messagesStream = builder.stream(
   Topic.Message.getKafkaName(),
   Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), new NoSqlSerde())
        .withTimestampExtractor((k, partitionTime) -> {
            Long measurementTime = ((SensorDataPojo) k.value()).getMeasurementTime();
            if (measurementTime != null) {
                return measurementTime;
            }
            return partitionTime;
        })
);

KStream<String, String> patientsWithSensors = messagesStream.map(
    (key, sensorDataPojo) ->
        new KeyValue<>(
            noSqlSensorDataPojo.getPatientId(),
            noSqlSensorDataPojo.getSensorId()
        )
);

KTable<String, SensorListSerde> patientsWithSensorsTable = patientsWithSensors.toTable(
   Named.as("patients-sensors-occurrences-table"),
   Materialized.<String, String>as(storeSupplier)
       .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
       .withValueSerde(sensorListSerde)
);
```

But using this I am unable to figure out how to properly store the timestamp of the latest record per sensor per patient in the table as well. I am assuming there must be a better way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it right now `KTable` has `PatientId` as a key and `SensorId` as a value. That means it would always contain the `SensorId` of the last measurements for each patient.

As you already now how to extract the timestamp from your data, you could define a pojo containing `timestamp` in addition to `sensorId` and use this as a value. You would have to use the `JsonPOJOSerializer` for this.

However, I am not sure why you want the latest occurence of your values in a KTable in the first place. What do you want to do with this?

- If you want to do some kind of aggreagation, you can do it in the stream as well.
- If you want to persist the latest data in a db, you are probably better of with Kafka Connect.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#timestamped-state-stores) and [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/latest/index.html)

---

EDIT:

I just stumbled across the `Stores.timestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder()` method in Kafka Streams. If you replace your first line by

```
TimeStampedKeyValueBytesStore PatientSensorSupplier = 
Stores.timestampedKeyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("latest-patient-sensor-occurrence"), Serdes.String(), sensorListSerde, Serdes.).build();
```

it might just work.

Comment: I want to persist the latest data in a database  preferably without using kafka connect. I'm currently using redis for storing these values, but since kafka has a store too, I'm investigating this route

Comment: I see. I guess this means you try to use [interactive queries](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html)? And I noticed you fall back to partition time if the timestamp extraction yields `null`. Is this also the behaviour you want in the state store? Or do you want to persist the timestamp as it was in the event?